# are there any c# libraries for Named Entity Recognition?

Tags: c#, dll, nlp

I am looking for any free libraries for Named Entity Recognition in c# or any other .net language.

Comment: @Taz: would you mind if the library were written in VB.NET or maybe F#?

Comment: Should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/), a port of the Java based OpenNLP, supports named entity tagging.

Comment: They are NLP libraries but is any of these recognize entities?

Comment: Look at SharpNLP's name finder. I thought Antelope had one as well. But, after looking at the package again, I'm actually not so sure. At least for now, I'm removing Antelope from the answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need to extract entities from text, you could try Open Calais from Thomson Reuters. It's free for up to 40K api calls/per day, and has worked well for me in the past. (I've been using it 2x/day for ~6 months without a hitch.)

They provide wrappers in various languages (for making api calls) and you can get the response in a few different formats as well.

Here's the link:

http://www.opencalais.com/

(I'm afraid I only know of NER libraries in Java and Python.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of Java implementations at universities ([like this one](http://nlp.stanford.edu/ner/index.shtml)), but no commercial version I am aware of.

The code for university versions is available, and with some effort could probably be ported to .NET.

Comment: This is limited to Person/Organization and Place only. I need one with more types. Code structure is too complex for me to do a manual conversion. Thanks for your answer.